# Running shell scripts in single-user mode

Tags: macos, bash, script, single-user

I'm planning on running a couple of scripts in [single-user mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) to speed up (and simplify for less savvy users than myself) the configuring of a few aspects of some Macs that I set up for other people.

I've read the few threads I could find about this, and my question is simply is there anything I should be particularly aware of when it comes to running scripts from single-user mode?

I'm aware that I can't invoke any commands/apps that would require a GUI to load, and that the `/sbin/fsck` and `/sbin/mount` commands would still be required before a script can be run at all.

Two more specific questions: If I set the script as executable before depositing it on the disk image that will be booted in single-user mode, will it remain executable?

And lastly, when it comes to removing user accounts I've seen on some threads [e.g this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23069/how-do-i-remove-a-user-via-single-user-mode-in-10-7) the need to invoke this command:

```
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist
```

However, as I simply want to `rm` various files - is there any need to do this, the process *seems* to work just fine without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, files flagged as executable will still be executable under Single User Mode.

opendirectoryd is just for handling logins/authentication and using root doesn't require that, and you don't need to launch it if you just intend to manage files.

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much! Will try to up-rep you etc once mine is high enough!